# Rails 4.2: How to forcefully reload (engine's) route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How to absolutely force to reload the routes in `before_action`? `Rails.application.reload_routes!` reloads the routes only if there is change in `routes.rb`.

Here is the chapter in [ActionDispatch::Routing](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing.html) about how to reload the route:

```
Reloading routes

You can reload routes if you feel you must:

Rails.application.reload_routes!

This will clear all named routes and reload routes.rb if the file has been modified from last load. To absolutely force reloading, use reload!.
```

There is no detail about how to force to reload except mentioning `reload!`. Tried `Rails.application.reload!` in `before_action` and it did not work. In `application controller`:

```
before_action :reload_route

def reload_route
  Rails.application.reload_routes!
end
```

If the engine name is `MyEngine`, what's the right way to force to reload its route?

Comment: why do you want to force reload the `route_helpers` in run time? this will not make any sense in `production`

Comment: For constant in routes.rb

Comment: `Rails.application.reload_routes!` may work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`config.paths["config/routes.rb"] << YOUR_ROUTE_FILE`

Comment: The path for engine's route file is `/my_engine/config/routes.rb`. Do we do `config.paths["config/routes.rb"] << "my_engine/config/routes.rb"` in `before_action`?